# Reading data columns, bit shifting, printing data to .txt file in C++

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I am currently trying to write data from a .txt file. The file (second.txt) contains 5 columns describing properties of a particle.

My intention is to read in the data from the columns(all having same lenth), store them into an array, bit shift each number so that I can have integers instead of decimals, and then write the new data to a new output.txt file in order to then work with it in Python (the only language in "kind of" know).

Here is my attempt so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

void saveArray(double* array)
{
int length = sizeof(array);
ofstream output("output.txt");
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
output<<array[i]<<endl;
}
}

int main()

{

ifstream inFile;

int cola, colb, colc, cold, cole;

inFile.open("second.txt");

inFile >> cola >> colb >> colc >> cold >> cole;

double n[cola];
double x[colb];
double y[colc];
double zeros[cold];
double r[cole];

for (int i = 0; i <= cola; ++i)
{
    inFile >> n[i];

};

for (int k = 0; k <= colb; ++k)
{
     inFile >> x[k];

};

for (int j = 0; j <= colc; ++j)
{
    inFile >> y[j];

};

for (int z = 0; z <= cold; ++z)
{
    inFile >> zeros[z];

};

for (int a = 0; a <= cole; ++a)
{
    inFile >> r[a];

};

int s = 2;

n << s;
x << s;
y << s;
r << s;

saveArray(n);
saveArray(x);
saveArray(y);
saveArray(r);

return 0;

}
```

I would greatly appreciate some hints on how to make this code work.

Comment: Why not perform the bitshifting in python and completely skip this step? Also, `i++` might be better suited than `++i` here.

Comment: `sizeof array` doesn't do what you think it does. It's not the number of elements in the array.

Comment: *shift each number so that I can have integers instead of decimals*:just cast `int()` and the decimal part will be gone...

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie or serialize ints in the first place, heh.

Answer (score 1):

*shift each number so that I can have integers instead of decimals*:

just cast `int()` and the decimal part will be gone...

Your `for` loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= cola; ++i)
//                 ^ the equal sign has to be removed
//                 since n[cola] doesn't exist
```

The way you are reading from your files will read rows instead of columns. Since you say *My intention is to read in the data from the columns(**all having same lenth**)* why do you need several ints: `cola`,`colb`,`colc`...??

In order to have your code reading from columns you have to write your `for` loop as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<nrchars; i++){
    inFile >> col1[i];
    inFile >> col2[i];
    ....
    inFile >> colN[i]; // Nth column
}
```

You will also have to modify your `saveArray()` since:

- `sizeof(array)` doesn't give you the length of the array. `sizeof(array)` will give the size of a pointer on your PC.
- The way you are writing to your file is again row-wise instead of column-wise